# Facebook Custom Story Link Not Working in Android but Does in iOS and Web

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting a custom story onto my Facebook timeline. This is fine and appears the way I expect.

The issue I am having is when I click on the story whilst using the Android Facebook application, the link opens in the browser but then comes up with the message "The page you requested was not found".

I am using the Android FacebookDialog to publish my OpenGraphObject and Action.

These links work fine when I click on the custom story using the iOS Facebook application and on the web version on Facebook.

Anyone else notice this?

Comment: Do you have deep linking turned on for Android in your app settings?

Comment: No I don't necessarily want to launch my application. I want it to go to a specific web page